# Solving $4^x + 7^x = 9^x$ algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across the question $4^x + 6^x = 9^x$ and found this was fairly easy to convert to a quadratic equation because of the ratio of 4, 6 and 9.

So I thought I'd try solving $4^x + 7^x = 9^x.$

I solved this graphically using Geogebra and found the answer is $x = 1.4574697.$   However, I can not figure out how to solve this algebraically.  Every approach that I try fails.

Any ideas as to how to go about this?

Comment: What makes you think there is an algebraic solution?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be?

Comment: @terrace, it's not an algebraic equation (that is, a polynomial equation), so if it has an algebraic solution, it's only by coincidence. Heck, even algebraic equations like $x^5-x-1=0$ don't have algebraic solutions.

Comment: Because there usually isn’t one. Most of the problems you’ve seen have been designed to teach you algebraic techniques. But the problems that can be solved using algebraic techniques are a very small subset of problems.

Comment: Maybe @Bibbs1000 wants only algebraically but I think a more interesting question is whether it can be solved at all using any technique

Comment: It's easy to solve $4^x + 6^x = 9^x$ because it's trivial to transform it into a quadratic ($(1.5^x)^2 - 1.5^x - 1 =0$) as you yourself have mentioned. But with the other equation, with all three numbers being pairwise coprime, this simple approach is not possible. In general, equations with the unknown in the exponent, and with two or more terms like that being added together, are not tractable to elementary algebraic solutions. They are called transcendental equations. (cont'd)

Comment: Usually, you need numerical methods for an approximate solution and you can't do better. Some can be solved with special functions like the Lambert W, but I don't think it works here.

Comment: @terrace He already solved it using a non-algebraic technique.

Comment: @terrace It can be solved numerically. It’s usually hard to prove a value has no closed form, in general

Comment: @Deepak Thanks for actually explaining why

Comment: Note that $2\cdot4^x+7^x=9^x$ has $x=2$ as an integer solution, which is easy to demonstrate. And there are ways to establish this equation has only one solution, so that would be the full argument for that equation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you look for the zero's of function $$f(x)=9^x-4^x - 7^x $$ It is very stiff; so let us consider instead
$$g(x)=\log(9^x)-\log(4^x+7^x)=x\log(9)-\log(4^x+7^x)$$ which is much more close to linearity which is very good for any numerical solver.

By inspection $g(1)=-\log \left(\frac{11}{9}\right)<0$. Making a Taylor series around $x=1$
$$g(x)=(\log (9)-\log (11))+(x-1) \left(-\frac{4 \log (4)}{11}-\frac{7 \log (7)}{11}+\log(9)\right)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, then an *estimate* is
$$x=\frac{4 \log (4)+7 \log (7)-11 \log (11)}{4 \log (4)+7 \log (7)-11 \log (9)}\sim 1.44122$$ Starting with this estimate, one or two iterations of Newton method will give the "exact" solution.

We could do better using **one** single iteration of Newton-like methods of order $n$ still using $x_0=1$. The formulae will be a bit messy but look at the numerical results
$$x_{(2)}=1.441218 \qquad x_{(3)}=1.457292\qquad x_{(4)}=1.457512$$

Comment: What does *stiff* mean in this context?

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Obviously, I use the wrong word. In French, we use *stiff* for a function which varies very fast, not only for ODE's. Which word do I need to use ? Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a good English word for a function that varies very fast. Maybe in some circles people use *stiff* for that, and I just wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Have a look at https://www.deepl.com/translator?utm_source=lingueebanner1&il=fr#fr/en/fonction%20raide

Comment: That shows that a literal translation of *fonction raide* is *stiff function*; it doesn't show that *stiff* is used in mathematical English. I remain agnostic.